# One to Many Relationship sqlalchemy id's

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Following [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many) tutorial, for the one to many relationships, I have this simple code:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```

Now the problem is populating `parent_id`, whenever I set the children as a list, and commit the results to a database as follows:

```
# assume I have a session
children = Child(), Child(), Child()
p = Parent(children=children)
session.add(p)
session.commit()
```

If I check the database at this point, `parent_id` is not populated. I guess this makes sense, because I haven't explicitly defined parent_id anywhere, but is there a way to get the children to get the parents id?

Answer (score -1):

Parent accept children as a list so:

```
children = [Child(), Child(), Child()]
...
p = Parent.query.first()
for child in p.children:
    print(child.parent_id)
```

Comment: What original poster has typed is a tuple, so I am afraid you did not answer question.